# Android: optimizing fragment transitions

Tags: java, android, optimization, transition

So in my app I have a bunch of fragments that the user navigates through. And there are a lot of methods in my activity class that are used for fragment transitions. These are very similar to each other with the only difference being the class of the newFragment. Here is one these methods:

```
public void onHelpSelected() {

    slideInRight();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            HelpFragment newFragment = new HelpFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            slideOutLeft();
        }

    }, 500);

}
```

Then, I also have a few classes that describe each fragment. These are also very similar to each other: they differ only by the amount of buttons and by what these buttons do (but most of the buttons are used for fragment transitions). Here is one of these classes:

```
    public class AuthFragment extends Fragment {

    Button authRegButton;
    Button authHelpButton;

    OnHelpButtonListener helpCallback;
    OnRegButtonListener regCallback;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_auth, container, false);


        authHelpButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.auth_help_button);
        View.OnClickListener authHelpListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                helpCallback.onHelpSelected();
            }
        };
        authHelpButton.setOnClickListener(authHelpListener);


        authRegButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.auth_reg_button);
        View.OnClickListener authRegListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                regCallback.onRegSelected();
            }
        };
        authRegButton.setOnClickListener(authRegListener);

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnHelpButtonListener {
        void onHelpSelected();
    }

    public interface OnRegButtonListener {
        void onRegSelected();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            helpCallback = (OnHelpButtonListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHelpButtonListener");
        }

        try {
            regCallback = (OnRegButtonListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnRegButtonListener");
        }
    }

}
```

So, I have many pieces of code that are very similar. I bet there is a way to make all this code look much nicer and work more efficiently.

Thus, my question is how do I do that? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved this problem, if someone ever needs this :)

So I made an abstract class for my fragments and worked out all the code there:

```
public abstract class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

MediaPlayer clickPlayer;
int layoutId;
View view;
OnButtonListener buttonCallback;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);

    return view;

}

public interface OnButtonListener {
    void onButtonSelected(LoginFragment fragment);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {
        buttonCallback = (OnButtonListener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnButtonListener");
    }

}

public MyButton setUpButton(int buttonId) {

    final MyButton button = (MyButton) view.findViewById(buttonId);
    View.OnClickListener authHelpListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            clickPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.click);
            clickPlayer.start();
            LoginFragment newFragment = determineFragment(button);
            buttonCallback.onButtonSelected(newFragment);
        }
    };
    button.setOnClickListener(authHelpListener);

    return button;

}

public LoginFragment determineFragment(MyButton button) {

    LoginFragment result;
    int buttonId = button.getId();

    switch (buttonId){

        case R.id.auth_help_button:
            result = new HelpFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.agr_cancel_button:case R.id.help_cancel_button:
        case R.id.reg_cancel_button:case R.id.reg_cont_cancel_button:
            result = new AuthFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.agr_back_button:case R.id.reg_cont_button:
            result = new RegContFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.reg_cont_agr_button:
            result = new AgrFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.auth_reg_button:
            result = new RegFragment();
            break;
        default:
            result = null;
            break;
    }

    return result;

}
```